# Water simulation (direction / pressure)

Tags: fluid-simulation

Do water simulations in Blender only go horizontal and down, or can you have water go vertically up from something like a fountain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your *Inflow* object, enable *Initial Velocity* and increase the *Z* value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a new feature? I remember struggling with this in version 2.8

Comment: Edit: I've just checked for 2.7 and there was already Velocity for the Inflow object

Comment: How to make it steady like a real fountain? @moonboots

Comment: @ Barbod M, it looks like it's just at the beginning that it gushes out like that, if you want to avoid that effect, you can bake the simulation then use the Offset value to make the simulation begin sooner (like -50 to make it begin 50 frames before frame 0)